# Redoing an ArcGIS Server post-install

Tags: arcgis-server, windows

I'd like to reconfigure an ArcGIS Server 10 Java implementation (single machine, Windows Server 2008 R2) and I plan to re-run the post-install.

Complete: I do not need to save anything on the current machine. To get the cleanest reinstall, I intend to delete the SOM, SOC & "Webservices" accounts; the agsusers & admin groups, and the five directories created (arcgiscache, arcgisindex, arcgisinput, arcgisjobs, & arcgisoutput).

Any other suggestions for redoing an ArcGIS Server 10 post-install?

*Update:* I reran the post-install and have quite a few notes. I posted them below and made this a community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two approaches to redo an ArcGIS Server post-install:

1. ***Partial:*** retain an existing setup (can be required after
       patches)
2. ***Complete:***  wipe an existing configuration (typically
       to fix an existing corrupted
       post-install)

Reconfiguring items created during post-install does not necessarily require running another post-install. Much of it, like changing server directories, can be done as an administrative task. ESRI states that post-install performs the following tasks ([web source](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_net_install_guide/index.html#/Configure_GIS_server/008900000016000000/)). They may be useful in determining whether a post-install is necessary.

- Create the SOM account and the SOC account (if necessary).
- Create agsusers and agsadmin user groups if they do not already
  exist.
- Register the ArcGIS Server Windows service and set the startup
  account to be the ArcGIS Server
  account.
- Set DCOM launch privileges for ArcSOM.exe and ArcSOC.exe (adds the
  ArcGIS Server account and the ArcGIS
  Container account).
- Set DCOM access privileges for ArcSOM.exe and ArcSOC.exe (adds the
  ArcGIS Server and ArcGIS Container
  accounts, as well as the agsusers and
  agsadmin user groups).
- Set DCOM identity for ArcSOC.exe to run as the ArcGIS
  Container account.
- DCOM is enabled if it is not already enabled on the machine. The
  GIS Server Post Install summary
  informs you if DCOM has been enabled.
- Grant write privileges on \cfg and
  \log of the
  ArcGIS Server account.
- Grant write privileges to the system TEMP directory for the ArcGIS
  Server account.
- Grant write privileges to the system TEMP directory for the ArcGIS
  Container account.
- Create the ArcGIS Manager account.
- Create the GIS server directory with cache, job, and output
  subdirectories.

*Note*: Not listed in this ESRI tasklist are: save a configuration XML file and the software licensing/authorization process; these happen during post-install too

**1. Approach Partial** Running post-install while retaining an existing setup

- Run post-install and fill out the forms in the same manner as your current configuration. If you have a configuration XML file from a previous post-install, use it.
  For authorization, I use a authorization file and found that the main authorization number did not propagate automatically into the forms after a patch install (as opposed on my initial post-install when the form autofilled). It was easy enough to open the authorization file, copy, and paste the code. However, you may want to have the authorization number(s) at hand.
- Prior configuration should still be valid, so configuration taks like adding users to groups should NOT be necessary. If you want to double check your users permissions, visit the help topic [Additional configuration steps using operating system tools](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_java_install_guide/index.html#/Additional_configuration_steps_using_operating_system_tools/008m00000011000000/). 
  I found that this help topic is more detailed in the version bundled with the software itself.

**2. Approach: Complete:** Wipe existing configuration (typically to fix an existing corrupted post-install)

- Delete the accounts SOM, SOC, & Webservices
- Delete user groups agsusers & admin
- Delete the five directories created: arcgiscache, arcgisindex, arcgisinput, arcgisjobs, & arcgisoutput)
- Run the post-install. During the post-install, you have the option to save a configuration XML. It may be useful if you have to do the procedure again.
- Perform the additional necessary configuration as described in the following links:  ([.net](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_net_install_guide/index.html#/Additional_configuration_steps_using_operating_system_tools/00890000001m000000/)) ([Java](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_java_install_guide/index.html#/Additional_configuration_steps_using_operating_system_tools/008m00000011000000/))

When I tested the Server, nothing worked, and I saw that the machine had two sets of server directories. I was certain I had deleted the directories from the previous install, but they were there nonetheless. The problem was easy to fix. I went into ArcCatalog and changed the server properties. Info on this can be found at: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Creating_a_server_directory_in_ArcCatalog/0093000000nw000000/
That same bank of ESRI help topics includes [Common Administrative Tasks](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Logging_in_to_Manager/0093000000n4000000/) and they may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> Mostly, I want to change the server directories to use a newly installed hard drive.

You should not have to re run the post installs to achieve this task
This [link it not quite what your looking for](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Creating_a_server_directory_in_ArcCatalog/0093000000nw000000/), but some links around it might help.

If you RC the admin connection to the server in ArcCatalog --> Hit the Directories tab
From here you can repoint the directories to your new drive.

Answer (score 1):

I export the XML file so that I can re-run the post install without rummaging through notes (or trying to remember what I typed in originally).